# Do statics need to be injected using MS Fakes?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

When shimming a static method with MS Fakes, it seems the class with the static method does not need to be injected into the class you are testing.  Is that always the case?

Comment: Are you asking if the entire container class needs to be replaced for shimming a static method then the answer is No.

Comment: If your test requires specific behavior from some static somewhere, it may indicate that the method under test is too tightly coupled. The result of the static call should be passed in. If you need to shim, that indicates your test knows the implementation details of the method, which is always bad. Shimming is almost always indicative of a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Static methods are available on the type, not on an instance so any method using the Type's static methods would be shimmed.